# In iOS apps , what's the difference between the main bundle and the documents directory?

Tags: ios, file

Can someone please explain it to me?

I want to know the difference between them regarding things like:

- The amount of space taken from the device (wether the the app is active or terminated).
- Memory usage.
- The ability to read and write data (on the user's end).
- What stays and what gets removed (or changed) when the app is: Updated form the Appstore/ Deleted.

And any other details you may find necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### the mainBundle is the installed app

- it is the size of the extracted ipa (you can see that in xcode beforehand)
- it is ReadOnly and won't contain user files (e.g. documents)
- deleted with your app (it is the app)
- when updating from the App Store, older ioses replace the whole bundle, downloading it as a whole. newer oses 6+ IIRC, do delta updates, only downloading changed files. you can't say how much is downloaded -- at least the amount of bytes you changed.

### the documents dir is where your user generated contents are stored.

- Its size depends on what your user/your app creates as documents ;) it starts with 0 mb
- It is ReadWrite
- deleted with your app
- remains untouched by updates

---

that answers question 1 and 3 and 4

question 2 is wrong .. a filesystem folder doesn't consume memory unless files are loaded by the app/the os

- the os obviously loads the necessary parts of your app and the required frameworks
- your app can load documents.

memory usage is only vaguely / not really related to file size

Comment: A nice answer. However, there are two more details I would like to know about: 1.What things change for each of the bundle and the docs dir when the app is updated form the Appstore? 2.Let's say I have a  resources folder , if I set the app to download it to the docs directory on first launch , will the iphone setting app usage page recognise a different size for the app from if I keep the folder in the main bundle ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping you would answer the second question in my previous comment since it's the one really intriguing me. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that. yes if you download it on launch, it won't be counted towards your app in the store

Comment: in the settings: the sum of MB for your app will stay though