# What is the difference between background state , InActive State & Non-running state of iOS App?

Tags: ios, iphone

Can you please explain me

1. What is the difference between background state , InActive State &  Not-running state of iOS App?
2. What is the difference between Main Bundle and Documents Directory?
   (Suppose I download a file/resource(e.g data.plist) from app ,so where can i find it? In Main Bundle or Documents directory or somewhere else?)

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

**1. What is the difference between background state , InActive State & Not-running state of iOS App?**

**InActive State**

The app is running in the foreground but is currently not receiving events. (It may be executing other code though.) An app usually stays in this state only briefly as it transitions to a different state.

**Background state**

The app is in the background and executing code. Most apps enter this state briefly on their way to being suspended. However, an app that requests extra execution time may remain in this state for a period of time. In addition, an app being launched directly into the background enters this state instead of the inactive state.

**Not-running state**

The app has not been launched or was running but was terminated by the system.

Please refer to [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) and following image for understanding more about App states

[image: App States]

**2. What is the difference between Main Bundle and Documents Directory? (Suppose i download a file/resource(E.g. data.plist) from app ,so where can i find it? In Main Bundle or Documents directory or somewhere else?)**

Main bundle is some thing which contains files which you have added along with the iPA . It is read only you can not add or remove files to main bundle programatically.

Document directory is empty when user installs the app and you can save and remove as many files as you want in it (Depending upon space available in the device). So the file which you download you can save it in document directory.

**Suggestion**

I would recommend you to read apple docs and other tutorials like [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/), it would really help you understand concepts better.

Comment: what happen if get any event in suspended state?

Comment: You won't get an event. iOS will decide if it wants to wake up your app. If it does, it will bring your app from the suspended to the background state and then hand you some time to process the event

Answer (score 6):

1. Please refer this [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/understand-the-states-and-transitions-of-an-ios-app/) for detailed info about iOS application states .

It says :

**Non-running** - The app is not running.

**Inactive** - The app is running in the foreground, but not receiving events. An iOS app can be placed into an inactive state, for example, when a call or SMS message is received.

**Active** - The app is running in the foreground, and receiving events.

**Background** - The app is running in the background, and executing code.

**Suspended** - The app is in the background, but no code is being executed.

2. At the time of downloading at dynamic time in app , we need to give path for the detination , that will be of Documents Directory .

Main Bundle is the space where you can add the files initally and ship with the ipa.

Detailed difference you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471024/in-ios-apps-whats-the-difference-between-the-main-bundle-and-the-documents-di)

Hope this solves your Query.

Comment: what happen if get any event in suspended state?