# State of the iOS app before launching

Tags: ios

What is the state of the iOS app when it is not launched or terminated by the user or os?. Is it suspended or not running?
I have read the app lifecycle documentation but i still have confusion.

Comment: It is in "not running" state. I think you should check this out; https://stackoverflow.com/a/38219444/1632968

Answer (score 0):

Not Running

Look at this link https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/understand-the-states-and-transitions-of-an-ios-app/

Answer (score 0):

Then the state of the app will be Not running .

**Not running**
The app has not been launched or was running but was terminated by the system.

[image]